# How do I export my source from TFS for import into CVS?

Tags: tfs, import, export, cvs

TFS version is 2010.  CVS version is 1.11.17.

Comment: Why go to CVS?  It's a far less modern source control product than TFS.  Maybe consider others, such as Subversion if you like CVS, or GIT or Mercurial or...

Comment: We're currently using CVS but I want to play around with TFS.  I want to know whether I can do this but still go back to CVS if I need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CVS is really a step back, but ok ;)
If you don't need any file history, it's very simple to export your source.

In VS2010, open View / Other Windows / Source Control Explorer.
Than open the drop-down "Workspace" and select "Workspaces ..."

There you can add a new Workspace, where you also can select your local folder to which you want to export the TFS source files.

After that you can click OK and retrieve the TFS files you want to the selected local folder.

The next step is to import all in CVS.

That's all.

**EDIT:**

I found a software tool that claims to offer source code migration from CVS to TFS. Perhaps it's worth to try: http://www.componentsoftware.com/Products/Converter/index.htm

Comment: Is it possible to include revision history?  That sounds like it just gives the current state of the files, and so they will appear in CVS with no prior history.  I believe when migrating between some source control programs it's possible to include a file's revision as well, ie it's a full conversion.

Comment: I know it's a step back :P  I only want to know whether I can try out TFS and still get my source and revision history back if things don't pan out.

Comment: I found a software tool that claims to offer source code migration from CVS to TFS. Perhaps it's worth to try: http://www.componentsoftware.com/Products/Converter/index.htm

Comment: That tool was built for 2005 and it is unlikley to work for 2010.

Comment: There's no easy way to do history, other than iterating through each individual change and replicating the action in the other repository.  This could be done through code, but I personally would never recommend it.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to look at the [TFS Integration Platform](http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/). You should be able to setup a 2-way sync of source so that both are kept up to date.

I don't think CVS is supported out-of-the-box, but there should be someone who has written an adapter.

There is a tool from [Timely Migration](http://www.timelymigration.com/cvs-to-tfs.aspx) that should integrate with the TFS IP.